# Remote computer batch script with input prompt

Tags: batch-file, shutdown

I am trying to write a batch script that shuts down a remote computer and prompts for the computer name. I've tried copying bits and pieces of scripts that I have found but so far nothing will work

This is what I have so far:

```
 @ECHO OFF
 set /p computer =Enter computer Name:
 shutdown -m %computer% -r -t 60
```

Comment: In the set command, remove the space between the variable name (computer) and the equals sign.

Answer (score 1):

This script should work. Please note I have removed the space between `computer` and `=Enter computer name`

```
@ECHO OFF
:InputComputerName
set /p computer=Enter computer Name:
IF "%computer%"=="" GOTO Error
    echo Shutting down %computer%
    shutdown -s -m \\%computer% -t 600 -c "The computer is shutting down. Please save your work."
GOTO End
:Error
ECHO You did not enter a computer name
GOTO :InputComputerName
:End
```